# ruby on rails flash messages - :alert :error :notice and :success?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, message, alert

In several of my controllers, I have redirects/flash messages

```
redirect_to products_url, :notice => "message here", 
redirect_to states_url, :error => "oops!" etc...
```

In my sessions controller, however, upon successful authentication, I have 
    flash[:success] = "welcome!"
    redirect_to user

I'd like to be able in my other controllers to do something like
    :success => "yay!"

This is mostly for cosmetic/consistency purposes, but are :notice, :alert and :error the only flash-types available / can I add additional types?  Am I making sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I believe without changes, this is as close as you'll get:

```
redirect_to user_path(@user), :flash => { :success => "Message" }
```

Here's some [additional notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20120418030526/http://archives.ryandaigle.com:80/articles/2009/12/20/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-set-flash-in-redirect_to) regarding the friendly flash syntax addition.

Answer (score 13):

I just found out that in Rails 4 you can register custom types in app controller:

```
class ApplicationController
    ...
  add_flash_types :error, :another_custom_type
end

# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ...
    redirect_to home_path,
      error: "An error message for the user"
  end
end

# app/views/home/index
<%= error %>
```

The merit goes to http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/register-your-own-flash-types-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access different types of flash messages styles based on bootstrap alert (success and warning), in you controller:

```
flash[:success] = "This works!"
```

And in your layout (most probably application.html.erb)

```
  <% if success.present? %>
      <p class="alert alert-success"><%= success %></p>
  <% end %>
```

Same thing with warning and other bootstrap alert styles.