# Attempting to delete my post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have this destroy controller:

```
def destroy
    Post.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Post Deleted."
    redirect_to users_url
  end
```

And this view:

```
<% @posts.each do |i| %>
<li>
This post was created at: <%= i.created_at %></br>
Contents of the post: <%= i.content %>
<%= link_to "Delete this post", @post, method: :delete, class: "black", data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
</li>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now when I make a delete, it just redirects me to the page i made it to in the controller, and thats it. In the server logs i get this:

```
Started DELETE "/users/17" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 22:49:31 +0200
Processing by UsersController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"iT08NreZv83WtImK6V9/jXZOpgtzwSLjlxB7T/wn0E4=", "id"=>"17"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '473b76458ca425d9bb927550e7a11eb292393d84' LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :admin_user rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 22:49:31 +0200
Processing by FormController#home as HTML
  Rendered form/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '473b76458ca425d9bb927550e7a11eb292393d84' LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 9.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

What am I missing in here?

Answer (score 0):

You have a before filter that is checking if your current user is an admin_user. Your logs show that your current user isn't so you are being redirected before you hit the destroy action.

Also you should send the flash message with the redirect. [See this post for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7578381/793330)

```
 redirect_to users_url, success: "Post Deleted."
```

Comment: But my posts model does not have before filters, only user model

Comment: Also if I did this with one admin account, it deleted the user not the post oO

Comment: This doesn't happen in Model... it happens in your UsersController. does ApplicationController have a before_action/before_filter? If you're inheriting from it then its before_actions will be run

Comment: But why would it check into my user controller if I am pointing into posts controller for the destroy. And my application controller only has the  `include SessionsHelper and
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception in` it

Comment: Linking my whole app if its any use also. https://github.com/Veske/form
The problem is in the posts_controller and view/posts

Comment: your log shows you're hitting __Started DELETE "/users/17"__ so for the scope of your question... you're hitting the wrong controller. Having said that your github app works fine for me. I fixed a few issues with it and gave you a pull request. FWIW you should check out http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ before going on you need to practice TDD as it'll keep you from pulling your hair out. good luck! :)